# Why has this answer not received a single upvote in almost 6 months?

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question

As with the following three threads:

- [Why did this question not get any votes in the last 5.5 months despite getting 61 views and comments from at least 3 different people?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/366/5)
- [Why is nobody voting on this question, but so many people are voting on the comments?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/5)
- [Why did this question not get any votes in the last 6 months despite getting 49 views and 4 upvotes on a comment?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/5)

### [This answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10940/5) has received 0 upvotes in nearly 6 months.

The author of the answer has written 6 answers and all of them have had at least 2 upvotes (and one of them had 9 upvotes, despite the question never being an HNQ!), but this answer has received 0 upvotes. I'm avoiding providing my reason because I don't want to bias the answers.